# Cómo restar 1 mes a SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, apex

Tengo la siguiente condición en una consulta:

```
to_char(to_date(resolved_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi am'),'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')
```

Sin embargo, necesito mostrar 1 mes anterior al actual, por ejemplo, mostrar Diciembre, aunque ya estemos en Enero. Esto porque la información se carga 1 mes después. Es decir, la info de Diciembre, se carga en Enero y la de Enero en febrero, y asi sucesivamente. De qué manera puedo hacer que la fecha siempre sea del año actual, pero que me vaya mostrando un mes antes?

El resultado sería, por ejemplo:

| Mes | Resolución |
| --- | --- |
| 12/2020 | 4.3 |
| 01/2021 | 5.6 |

Quiero que aunque SYSDATE indique 2021, se me muestre el mes anterior (Dic 2020), que es cargado en Enero de 2021. Gracias.

Comment: y que error te da

Comment: Me dice que no es un operador válido

Comment: Mira a ver lo nuevo que puse

Comment: La Columna (o es una variable?) "resolved_time" es de que tipo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la **función ADD_MONTHS**, la cual aumenta o disminuye los meses de una fecha, para disminuir como en tu caso usarías un número negativo,(**-1**).

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('25/02/2020','DD/MM/YYYY'),-1) FROM DUAL;
```

Aquí le resto un mes a la fecha **25/02/2020**, la cual debería arrojar **25/01/2020**.

Para obtener el año actual prueba esto:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR') from dual
```

O:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') from dual
```

O:

```
select campos from tabla where extract(year from campo_fecha) = extract(year from sysdate)
```

Esta última creo que te va a ayudar mucho en tu caso.

La primera y tercera consulta devuelven el año de una fecha como un entero, mientras que la segunda como una cadena de caracteres.

**Referencias**:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/add_months.php

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_add_months.htm

Comment: Eso intenté, sin embargo lo necesito como condicionante, pregunta: puedo usar ADD_MONTHS como condición? Porque lo intenté y me dice que no es un operador válido.

Comment: Probaste el ejemplo que te puse,  pruébalo y aclararme eso de condicionante

Comment: Primero prueba el ejemplo que te puse y después adaptarlo a tu código, pero primero pruébalo como te lo puse

Comment: Sí, en efecto, el ejemplo de tu primera respuesta es justamente lo que necesito. Sin embargo, el reporte es anual. La condicionante que busco es porque me piden que la información presentada solo sea del año presente. Por esa razón uso SYSDATE. Mi pregunta es como usar ADD_MONTHS con un WHERE

Comment: Mira a ver lo nuevo que puse

Comment: Voy a utilizarlo, te agradezco mucho. Espero me sirva. Gracias!

Comment: Si te es de utilidad, por favor no olvides aceptar la respuesta